# Motivation For Tensor Product of R-Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, intuition, motivation

I have recently learned about tensor products of modules,specifically the material in Dummit and Foote chapter 10 section 4.  My understanding is that the construction of tensor spaces is important because they are a natural staging area for studying R-multilinear functions on a product of modules.

In linear algebra, I know of a few multilinear functions that are useful: like the inner product or the determinant, and also forms and metrics on manifolds.  However, I've never really seen how the language of tensor products of vector spaces is really helpful in working with those two examples.  Further, and more importantly, I can't think of any examples of why I would need to think about a bilinear or multilinear function on an R-module where R isn't a field.

Could anyone provide a tangible result that is simplified by using these constructions and especially some motivation for why I should care about R-multilinear functions when R isn't a field?  In particular, how do the concepts of tensor products connect with other areas of mathematics or applications.

Comment: Exterior powers are useful, e.g., in proving determinantal identities: see, e.g., the PPPPS in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177259/why-does-this-antisymmetric-product-factor-out-a-determinant/177277#177277 . Tensor products themselves are somewhat less useful in proofs (though I am pretty sure they have applications -- I just don't remember any right off the bat; I would guess that the isomorphism $k\left[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\right] \otimes k\left[Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_m\right] \cong k\left[X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n, Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_m\right]$ allows reducing several ...

Comment: ... properties of multivariate polynomial rings to the univariate case by induction), but they are necessary to define many important notions, such as the abovementioned exterior powers.

Comment: (See http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870885710298 for another application of exterior powers.)

Comment: The next section in Dummit & Foote introduces projective, injective and flat modules. It also proves the [tensor-hom adjunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction). These concepts are based on the tensor product, and are crucial in homological algebra, commutative algebra, algebraic topology and algebraic geometry. For example, see the [Künneth theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem); it allows you to compute the homology groups of a product space via the tensor product. There are many, many more examples. Just keep going. :)

Comment: If you can get ahold of [this](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Algebra_Volume_3_Modules.html?id=M7R9PgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) book, it explains tensors clearly.